# Undefined contract address with simple deployment

Tags: contract-deployment, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to get the address of a deployed contract, but I'm getting `undefined`. This is how I'm deploying:

```js
const Init = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("InitUpgradeV2");
const init = await Init.deploy(); 
await init.waitForDeployment();
console.log('Init deployed to: ', init.address); //undefined
```

This is my `hardhat.config`:

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require('dotenv').config();


module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.21",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: process.env.ARBITRUM,
        blockNumber: 136177703
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I've tried adding a `defaultNetwork`, removing the working and running on hardhat's network, specifying the network when deploying in the console `npx hardhat run script/deploy.js --network hardhat`, but same result.

You used to be able to do `await init.deployed()` but it seems that's no longer a function.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, to get the address of the contract, you don't do `init.address`, but `init.target`.

```js
"ethers": "^6.7.1",
"hardhat": "^2.17.4"
```